# My void function returns a value and does not return to the main function.

Tags: c, function, return, void

I was writing a program that asks the pilot to enter coordinates. Then, use those coordinates later on in other functions such as calculating the distance and the angle of the plane

this is my main function:

```
    int main()
{
    plane_checker();
    double angle_finder(int x, int y);
    double distance_plane(int x, int y, int z);
    void ils_conditions();
}
```

where my `plane_checker()` function is:

```
plane_checker()
{
    printf("Please enter your identification code:");
    scanf("%s", &plane_name[0]);

    if( (plane_name[0]== 'j') || (plane_name[0]== 'f') || (plane_name[0]== 'm') || (plane_name[0]== 'J') || (plane_name[0]== 'F') || (plane_name[0]== 'M'))
    {
        printf("Sorry, we are not authorized to support military air vehicles.");;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter your current coordinates in x y z form:");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);

        if(z < 0)
        {
            printf("Sorry. Invalid coordinates.");
        }

    }
    return;
}
```

after the user inputs the coordinates, I expect the program to return to the main function and continue with the other functions. However, when I run the program, my function returns the inputted z value and ends the program. As seen here:

```
Please enter your identification code:lmkng
Please enter your current coordinates in x y z form:1 2 2

Process returned 2 (0x2)   execution time : 12.063 s
Press any key to continue.
```

What could be the cause of this? I checked my program word by word but could not find the reason behind this? What am I missing?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: @Schwern I did not declare them inside main. I declared them before. I just called them in main

Comment: "*I expect the program to return to the main function and continue with the other functions.*" Those aren't function calls, they're forward declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont want your function to return anything define it like this

```
void plane_checker()
{
    printf("Please enter your identification code:");
    scanf("%s", &plane_name[0]);

    if( (plane_name[0]== 'j') || (plane_name[0]== 'f') || (plane_name[0]== 'm') || (plane_name[0]== 'J') || (plane_name[0]== 'F') || (plane_name[0]== 'M'))
    {
        printf("Sorry, we are not authorized to support military air vehicles.");;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter your current coordinates in x y z form:");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);

        if(z < 0)
        {
            printf("Sorry. Invalid coordinates.");
        }

    }

}
```

however you wont be able to manipulate the inserted data outside plane_checker function. You should return inserted data from your `plane_checker()` or use pointers. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

Comment: I tried doing void plane_checker() instead but it still returned the inputted z value. About the pointers, I havent learned them yeu but will check it out! thanks

Comment: did you remove return; from the end?

Comment: oh I did not see that you had removed that. I removed it and it worked now! Thanks a lot

Comment: by the way, If I point x y z in the int x, y, z; part, would that solve it?

Comment: glad to help, please marked my answer as correct if it helped you.
And I dont understand the last question ( by the way, If I point x y z in the int x, y, z; part, would that solve it? )

Comment: you told that the inputted x y z values in my function cannot be manipulated unless I use pointers. I know what pointer is and what is its purpose etc. But I do not know where to point them. Inside the function or when I declare it as global variable?

Answer (score 2):

Turn on warnings (`-Wall`) and it will tell you that `plane_checker` because you didn't specify it in the declaration it has an implicit `int` return value.

```
test.c:1:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
plane_checker()
^
```

You'll also get many other warnings and errors about undeclared variables: x, y, z, and plane_name. Fix them all. If they're globals they should not be.

---

> *"I expect the program to return to the main function and continue with the other functions."*

Those aren't function calls, they're forward declarations of functions. A function call would be like `angle_finder(x, y)`.

I'm sorry to say that your code is loaded with mistakes. I'd recommend you take a step back and read some more material on programming in C.

Comment: Yes, I am a beginner level coder. As far as I have understood, when I call a function in my main function, I should not declare what type of a function it is?

Comment: @Huzo Again, there are so may things wrong with your code I'd recommend you take a step back and work through a tutorial. I found [Learn C The Hard Way](https://learncodethehardway.org/c/) excellent, but I already had some experience in C and much experience at programming. The [C tutorial on TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/index.htm) might help.

Comment: @Huzo Function declarations go outside functions (preferably in headers). Function calls are what you need in `main`.

Comment: I understood my problem. :) I thought that I had to declare the function again when calling it in my main function. But it turned out that just calling the function was enough without declaring its type again. Thanks!